# Express $\cos(5t)$ with the help of Euler formula

Tags: signal-processing

I can't figure out, how to express $\cos(5t)$ in the form $e^{j\omega t}$. I don't even know the right answer. How would you deal with this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$
$$e^{-ix} = \cos x - i\sin x$$

it follows that

$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

and therefore

$$\cos (5t) = \frac{e^{5it}+e^{-5it}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just use that $\text{Re}(z)=\dfrac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$